# Scala SQLite Invalid Query for DELETE

Tags: sqlite, scala, exception, slick, delete-row

I have problem when trying to add a row and then delete one row from a table. What I have now is:

```
   def addItem(item:Item)={
        val query = items.filter(_.name === name)
        items += (item.name,item.timestamp)
        if(query.list.length > 10)
        {
         query.sortBy(timestamp).take(1).delete
        }
    }
```

It is supposed to store 10 latest items in the database by removing the oldest if there is more than 10.

But I get an error saying

```
SlickException : Invalid query for DELETE statement: A single source table is required, found List((s2,Comprehension))
```

I do have another table in the database but this should have nothing to do with that, there is not even a relation between the two tables.

Do you have any ideas what might be wrong? Or is there another way of keeping only last 10 values in the DB. The time stamp is java.sql.timestamp and I'm using Slick library for the SQLite for scala. Also the class Item is just holding a string and a timestamp.

Thanks! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Delete and take don't mix well if I remember correctly

Comment: Any ideas how to select the first element without using take?

Comment: Does SQL even support that? DELETE ... LIMIT ...? Slick can't do what SQL cant. :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that `delete` doesn't work with `take` for some reason, as was mentioned in the comments. There doesn't seem to be any other way to select the first element of the query as query other than `take`. `.first` for example returns the actual data of the row rather than a query of the first element and therefore `delete` can't be applied to it.
What I did to get it working was a sort of workaround:

```
val oldestTime = query.sortBy(timestamp).first._2 //selects the timestamp of the oldest element
query.filter(._timestamp === oldestTime).delete // deletes all rows with that timestamp
```

I hope this helps someone someday.